# Scrollspy jquery doesn't work in firefox, opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, opera

Please help me with this problem.
My script doesn't work in firefox and opera, it work's only in chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/suenot/2Fju6/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var navsPosition = $('#goods-navs').position().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $('body').get(0).scrollTop > navsPosition) {
            $('#goods-navs').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#goods-navs').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var navsPosition = $('#goods-navs').position().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > navsPosition) {
            $('#goods-navs').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#goods-navs').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

use "$(window).scrollTop()" instead of "$('body').get(0).scrollTop"

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#comment-133682921 <- this commment says that "$("html").scrollTop()" would work too. Maybe you'll need an if statement to check which browser the client is using. Or just check which one on them is holding a value